# HTML select POSTing text instead of value for <option> selected

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

For some reason, a form I am submitting via POST is sending the option text rather than the option value for a form. This is my select declaration:

```
<select name = "newfreq">
     <option val='1'>every week</option>
     <option val='2'>every 2 weeks</option>
</select>
```

When I print out my $_POST array in PHP. I have:

```
 [newfreq] => every 2 weeks
```

I am particularly new to jquery, which I am using to present the form modally, so I am pasting the full form/div and javascript below in case it's relevant:

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


  <script>
  $(function() {
    var dialog, form,



    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,

    });

     form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
     // event.preventDefault();

    });

    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
  </script>


<input id = "create-user" type="submit" tabindex="-1" value = "Change deal" >

<div id="dialog-form" >


  <form method = "post" action = "details.php">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Number of hours</label>
      <input type="text" name="newhours" id="name" value = <?php echo $totalhours; ?>  class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="email">Frequency</label>
      <select name = "newfreq">
           <option val='1'><?php echo return_frequency($typedeal ,1)?></option>
            <option val='2'><?php echo  return_frequency($typedeal ,2); ?></option>
      </select>

      <input type = "hidden" name = "included" value = '<?php echo $included;?>'/>
      <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = '<?php echo $id_bus;?>'/>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" >
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

return_frequency() is a php function that returns "every 2 weeks" or "every week" depending on the input.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to:

```
<select name = "newfreq">
 <option value='1'>every week</option>
 <option value='2'>every 2 weeks</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<option val='1'>` should be `<option value='1'>`

I know its probably Jquery that confused you since they use `.val` a lot but actual HTML uses `value` and so does normal Javascript use `.value`.

I think since you didn't properly specify a value your browser must be putting the text in `value` for you somehow.  Don't rely on that, however, since I think that's probably a bug and not all browsers will do it.